# Servicestack JsConfig with emitLowercaseUnderscoreNames = true does not work on properties with alphanumeric names

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I am using Servicestack JsonConfig for serializing and deserializing the JSON. but for the following class, it works for some properties and does not for others.

```
        public class Address
         {
            public string Street1 { get; set; }
            public string Street2 { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
            public string ZipCode { get; set; }
         }
```

When I deserialize it to JSON ZipCode is correctly represented as "zip_code" but Street1 is represented as "street1" where the expected presentation is "street_1". Following is the code

```
    using (JsConfig.With(emitLowercaseUnderscoreNames: true, propertyConvention: PropertyConvention.Lenient))
      {
           //serialize into json
           requestJsonString = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(request.SubscriptionRequest);
      }
```

The part of the JSON I am getting is

```
{"address":{"street1":"100 Tlllbow Street","street2":"100 Taljjow Street","city":"Housthgon","state":"hg","zip_code":"022"}}
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is by design, you can change it by providing an alias with `[DataMember(Name]` attribute, e.g:

```
[DataContract]
public class Address
{
   [DataMember(Name="street_1")]
   public string Street1 { get; set; }
   [DataMember(Name="street_2")]
   public string Street2 { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string City { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string State { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Or by renaming your properties:

```
public class Address
{
   public string Street_1 { get; set; }
   public string Street_2 { get; set; }
}
```